Mongo C# Driver fails Bson Serialization for Compound Must clauses in $search aggregation
I have an Atlas Search index, and I'm using MongoDb Compass to write a $search aggregation, I was able to get the following syntax working and successfully returning results from Compass:
{
  index: "ShipmentProjections",
  compound: {
    must: {
      equals: {
        value: 208414,
        path: "MerchantId",
      },
    },
    must: {
      in: {
        path: "ShipmentId",
        value: [100405234]
      }
    }
  },
}

My problem is that I can’t convert this query into C#. I am using the MongoDb C# Bson driver (Nuget: MongoDb.Bson 2.23.2), but when I try to pass this query into BsonDocument.Parse(searchQuery), I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate element name 'must'.
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Add(BsonElement element)
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Add(String name, BsonValue value)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonValueSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Parse(String json)

However, it seems like having duplicate must elements within the compound statement is the required format of the query.
It seems as if there is a conflict between the syntax $search stage is requiring, and the uniqueness constraints on the BsonDocument's keys in the C# driver.
From my testing various ways of writing the query from Compass, I have found:

the must clause may only contain one condition (and and does not appear to be a valid option within must)
the compound statement doesn't support and either
So the only way I've been able to make this query pass validation is by having two distinct must keys nested under compound, with one condition nested within each must statement

Is there any way to get the BsonDocument in the C# driver to accept this search query with it’s duplicate must keys? Is there an alternative way to write the same query that avoids the duplicate key issues?
Thanks for your help!

FYI, your Compass query with two must clauses doesn't actually work. It's that it doesn't throw an error. One of the clauses will overwrite the other; possibly the 2nd clause will overwrite the 1st, if that's the spec. So it's actually processing just one of those clauses, which would have been spotted by checking either the query logs or the search results.

Aha, answer found from another board. It's as simple as converting the must clause to an array.
compound: {
    must: [
      {
        equals: {
          value: 208414,
          path: "MerchantId",
        },
      },
      {
        in: {
          path: "ShipmentId",
          value: [10654081],
        },
      }
    ]
  },

